# S3 transfer manager takes huge time to upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awss3transfermanager

I am uploading my application objects to s3 via transfer manager. It works fine except rare cases where it takes as huge as 15 minutes for an 300 KB object size. I  am just exploring to introduce retry logic so that I can say after 30 seconds abort current upload and resubmit it. Below is my code

```
private static UploadResult put(
            final AmazonS3 amazonS3,
            final Supplier<PutObjectRequest> requestSupplier) throws Exception {
        TransferManager tx = TransferManagerBuilder
                .standard()
                .withS3Client(amazonS3)
                .build();
        try {
            Upload myUpload = tx.upload(requestSupplier.get());

            return myUpload.waitForUploadResult();
        } finally {
            tx.shutdownNow(false);
        }
    }
```

Can we have something which can allow me to timeout this upload request after say 30 seconds so that I can retry again. waitForUploadResult method is a blocking call so cant do anything about it but wait for it to complete.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your application start afresh each time it uploads to S3 or is it the same application instance running for an extended period of time, uploading a lot of files and eventually hitting this problem?

Comment: Hi...  Pardon I didn't quite get you,  if you mean whether same transfer manager instance used everytime or new instance is created for each upload,  we create new transfer manager instance for each upload.  It is working fine except very rare cases which takes lot of time as I explained.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I was hoping to understand if your application runs for a long time (days) and over time perhaps your application or the SDK that it uses is leaking resources and that's the root cause of the problem. Or does your application have a short lifetime (hence each upload is from a new instance of your application and it's unlikely to be a problem related to resource leakage).

Comment: Ah thanks for clarification. My application runs on ec2 instance which dies after certain time say an hour.

Comment: Have you tried using waitForCompletion rather than waitForUploadResult .

Comment: @MadhavKumarJha As per docs, It does the same thing right, wait for completion of task.

Comment: Yes .. they do almost same thing ..but still give it a try.  and poll the upload status frequently until its done and log it.

Comment: Is there any chance of network breakage ?

Comment: @MadhavKumarJha Thanks but its a blocking call, it means it will not allow code following it to be executed. Does not fit what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Both are blocking call, only difference is the one you are using will return the UploadResult.  could you share s3 client instantiation code as well.

Comment: and instantiation of PutObjectRequest as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to timeout the upload request so I submitted it in an executor so waiting part runs in separate thread. Below is my code

```
private static UploadResult put(
            final AmazonS3 amazonS3,
            final Supplier<PutObjectRequest> requestSupplier) throws Exception {
        TransferManager tx = TransferManagerBuilder
                .standard()
                .withS3Client(amazonS3)
                .build();
        ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Upload myUpload = tx.upload(requestSupplier.get());
        try {
            Future<UploadResult> f = ex.submit(() -> myUpload.waitForUploadResult());
            return f.get(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (TimeoutException te) {
            myUpload.abort();
            throw new RuntimeException("S3 save operation timeout after 2 minutes. Aborted.", te);
        } finally {
            ex.shutdownNow();
            tx.shutdownNow(false);
        }
    }
```